# Ajax send parameters php doesn't receive it

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to send parameters from AJAX to PHP but that is not happening and I don't know why. This is a simple code. All I want to do is to send parameter
`param` to the same form and print the value to the page.

Source Code

PHP:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET))
    {
        echo $_GET["param"];
    }

?>
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>    
        <td><input type="text" id="myText" /></td>
        <td style="width:35px;"><div id='myDiv' style=" display:none;"><img src="30.gif" id="myImage" /></div></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="button" name="myButton" onClick="myFunction()"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display='inline';
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
        {
            setTimeout("callMe()",3000);    
        }

    }       
    xmlHttp.open("GET","myAjax.php?param=1",true);
    xmlHttp.send(); 
}

function callMe()
{
    document.getElementById('myText').value=xmlHttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display='none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get any browser console errors? Also, you should probably change `isset($_GET)` to `isset($_GET["param"])`

Comment: Note that using setTimeout method you are telling the browser to update the input field only after 3 seconds. Tried on Safari and Firefox the example works as expected.

Comment: @JeremyHarris i got this in console

GET http://localhost:8081/myAjax.php?param=1 200 OK 0ms

Comment: It's working fine in chrome, firefox and explorer, what do you get from   [http://localhost:8081/myAjax.php?param=1](http://localhost:8081/myAjax.php?param=1)? maybe are you doing a http request but this port is for https?

Comment: @IS_ELKADY Are you sure the `callMe` function has access to the `xmlHttp.responseText` value? It may be out of scope.

Comment: you know I tried firefox,safari,chrome,opera and ie I tried also IIS and apache I tried $_GET["param"] and the same result don't know exactly what is the problem.

Comment: try `var_dump($_GET)` and post output here

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
if (isset($_GET['param'])) {
    echo $_GET['param'];
}
```

It works well when I have tested.